# Can't compile Hello World in F*

Tags: ocaml, formal-verification, fstar

Both OCaml and F* have been successfully installed. The only thing resembling a Hello World example I was able to find was:

```
module Hello

open FStar.IO

let main = print_string "Hello F*!\n"
```

from its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/FStarLang/FStar/blob/master/examples/hello/Hello/Hello.fst).

I verified it with `fstar.exe hello.fst --codegen OCaml --extract_module Hello` and got back:

```
Extracted module Hello
hello.fst(5,0-5,38): (Warning 272) Top-level let-bindings must be total; this term may have effects
Verified module: Hello
All verification conditions discharged successfully
```

I looked up how to specify an IO total effect and tried changing it to `let main : unit -> Tot (IO unit) = print_string "Hello F*!\n"`, but got back `(Error 72) Identifier not found: [Tot]`. If anyone knows the proper way to declare a total top-level binding, that would be great.

For now, I removed the effect and accepted the warning. I then used `ocamlopt -o hello Hello.ml` as recommended in the documentation and got back:

```
File "Hello.ml", line 1, characters 5-10:
1 | open Prims
         ^^^^^
Error: Unbound module Prims
```

This is what is in `Hello.ml`:

```
open Prims
let (main : unit) = FStar_IO.print_string "Hello, F*!\n"
```

I know F* is a niche language, but I love what it has to offer and I hope others are able to help me get off the ground.

Comment: Where does `ocamlopt -o hello Hello.ml` link the `Prims` module into the code?

Comment: @Chris that's likely a big part of the problem. I do see `prims.fst` in `fstar/lib/fstar`, and I tried using the `--include` flag to point here, but maybe I used this flag incorrectly or maybe this isn't the way to reference prims at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps that ended up working for me:

Install with `opam pin add fstar --dev-repo`

Adjust source:

```
module Hello

open FStar.IO
open FStar.All

let main
  : unit  -> ML unit
  = fun _ -> print_string "Hello, F*!\n"

let _ = main ()
```

Extract with: `fstar.exe hello.fst --codegen OCaml --extract_module Hello`

Compile with:

```
OCAMLPATH=~/.opam/default/lib/fstar/ 
ocamlfind opt -package fstar.lib -linkpkg Hello.ml -o Hello
```